# How to set dynamic path in Page.ResolveUrl in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have tried in following way but it is not working.
Can any one tell me how to bind dynamic path. Even i am not getting any error.

```
$(document).on('click', 'i.btnFileDownload', function () {
            var file = $.trim($(this).parent().find("input.hdnfilepath").val());
            $("#lblExpFileName").html(file);
            var uri = '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/MyFolder/" + lblExpFileName.Text)%>';
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = file;
            link.href = uri;
            link.click();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create one variable for fixed base path and then append the dynamic part to it as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', 'i.btnFileDownload', function () {
    var file = $.trim($(this).parent().find("input.hdnfilepath").val());
    $("#lblExpFileName").html(file);
    var basePath = '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/MyFolder/")%>';
    var uri = basePath + $("#lblExpFileName").html();
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = file;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But still i am getting uri=/MyFolder/

Comment: I got it thank you. i used $("#lblExpFileName").html() now i am getting complete uri